# How to install memcached 3.1.4 for PHP 7.4 with brew on macOS Catalina?

Tags: php, macos, memcached, homebrew, pecl

The command `pecl install memcached` fails to compile:

```
[…]
ched/1.0.18_2/include -c /private/tmp/pear/temp/memcached/php_memcached.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o .libs/php_memcached.o
/private/tmp/pear/temp/memcached/php_memcached.c:3237:7: error: expected ';' after expression
        ulong key_index;
             ^
             ;
/private/tmp/pear/temp/memcached/php_memcached.c:3237:2: error: use of undeclared identifier 'ulong'
        ulong key_index;
        ^
/private/tmp/pear/temp/memcached/php_memcached.c:3237:8: error: use of undeclared identifier 'key_index'
        ulong key_index;
              ^
/private/tmp/pear/temp/memcached/php_memcached.c:3250:49: error: use of undeclared identifier 'key_index'
        ZEND_HASH_FOREACH_KEY_VAL(Z_ARRVAL_P(options), key_index, key, value) {
                                                       ^
/private/tmp/pear/temp/memcached/php_memcached.c:3255:44: error: use of undeclared identifier 'key_index'
                        if (!php_memc_set_option(intern, (long) key_index, value)) {
[…]
```

```
[…]
sasl_done();
                ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sasl/sasl.h:727:18: note: 'sasl_done' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
LIBSASL_API void sasl_done(void) __OSX_AVAILABLE_BUT_DEPRECATED(__MAC_10_0,__MAC_10_11,__IPHONE_NA,__IPHONE_NA);
                 ^
2 warnings and 5 errors generated.
make: *** [php_memcached.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

Xcode is up to date, PHP 7.4 is running fine, other packages installed with PECL are working good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Memcached Version 3.1.5 was installed today without problems by running `pecl install memcached`